# JSON Array parsing through iterator

Tags: android, arrays, json, iterator

I have a `json` `array` like this -:

```
"custom_attributes": [
            {
                "attribute_code": "description",
                "value": "Darkly sophisticated aromas take you into Siberia"},
            {
                "attribute_code": "color",
                "value": "6"
            },
            {
                "attribute_code": "options_container",
                "value": "container2"
            },
            {
                "attribute_code": "required_options",
                "value": "0"
            },
            {
                "attribute_code": "gift_message_available",
                "value": "2"
            },
            {
                "attribute_code": "brand",
                "value": "Molton Brown "
            },
            {
                "attribute_code": "supplier",
                "value": "Molton Brown "
            },
            {
                "attribute_code": "features",
                "value": "Twilight "
            }
        ]
```

I want to parse it through `iterator`. My keys are `attribute_code` and value.

Please help me for this parsing.

Comment: show your work please. Invalid JSON

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya JSON is valid. This is an array with same keys all over.I want to get, suppose "description." I dont want to write like getJsonObject(0). Instead i want iterator to find the attr code "description" and its specific value

Comment: Just write a for-loop. That's exactly what iterating means.

Comment: Leave I have done it through HashMap

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is invalid. It should be starting with [ so just remove the key  "custom_attributes" used for json array.

Comment: I want to iterate inside array. Just ignore what is custom array.

Comment: Leave I have done it through HashMap

Comment: Actually problem is not with iteration, the json you posted here are invalid you can check that from https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer, you first need to make a valid json, then you will be able to iterate that json array.